# Does Python's raw_input interfere with socat?

Tags: python, stdin, socat

I am trying to use this program plus socat to emulate a serial device.

```
#echo.py
n=0
while True:
    s = raw_input()
    if 'query' in s:
        print n
    n+=1
```

When I try to link the program to a fake serial port with

```
sudo socat -ddd -ddd PTY,raw,link=/dev/ttyS32,echo=0 EXEC:"python echo.py"
```

I don't get anything when reading or writing from the port. If I use READLINE instead of EXEC, serial data is transferred to and from the socat terminal with no problem.  Is `raw_input` doing something behind the scenes that is preventing socat from providing it a normal stdin?

Comment: ``raw_input`` does a lot of things you may not want if you're just trying to read from stuff piped to stdin (For example, displaying a prompt). Try using ``sys.stdin.read()/readline()`` instead.